# Mongodb Transactions - Unable to read from a snapshot

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, transactions

I am trying MongoDB transactions with mongoose but on every request to create a database and insert a user and a company, I am getting the following error

"Unable to read from a snapshot due to pending collection catalog changes; please retry the operation. Snapshot timestamp is Timestamp(1584451745, 1). Collection minimum is Timestamp(1584451753, 1)"

On retrying the request it works. But When I send a new request to create a new database and insert a user and a company, I get the same error. I always need to retry the request to successfully insert the data.

```
const session = await mongoose.startSession();
session.startTransaction();

try {
  await db.createCollection("users");
  await db.createCollection("companies");

  const savedUser = await UserModel({
    ...userDetails,
  }).save({ session });


  const company = await new CompanyModel({
    ...companyDetails
  }).save({ session });


  await session.commitTransaction();

  return { message: "User Added Successfully" };

} catch (err) {
  error("Transaction Error", err);
  await session.abortTransaction();
  throw err;
} finally {
  session.endSession();
}
```

Any idea what I am missing here?

Comment: Why do you need to create a collection `users` for every request ?

Comment: @WanBachtiar Actually I am creating a new DB on each request, so will need to create a user collection and company collection before inserting the data (I missed collection creation code for company model, I have updated in my question snippet)

Comment: @WanBachtiar also updated the question for a better understanding of the scenario.

Comment: Could you test with createCollection() option `writeConcern: "majority"` ? See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.createCollection/#db.createCollection

Comment: Did anyone find solution to this?

Answer (score 9):

Ok, I figured this out. As per mongoose documentation, you need to have collections created before using transactions:

```
Model.createCollection()
Parameters
[options] «Object» see MongoDB driver docs
[callback] «Function»
```

> Create the collection for this model. By default, if no indexes are specified, mongoose will not create the collection for the model until any documents are created. Use this method to create the collection explicitly.

> Note 1: You may need to call this before starting a transaction See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/#transactions-and-operations

source: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.createCollection

Comment: This answer pointed me in the right direction. For anyone encountering the same error but is not creating a collection, 'getting' a non-existing collection creates it, hence the error. To fix it make sure you are getting only existing collections.